# middle of vector of any type

Tags: c

I have the following data structure:

```
typedef struct {
      size_t d; /* dimension of elements*/
      TFComp fid; TFComp ord; /* fid and ord are some comparation functions*/
      char *v, *s, *t; /* v points to the starting point of vector; s points to end of usable area of vector; t points to the end of available area */
      } TMultime;
```

and the declarations:

```
TMultime *m;

char *p=m->v; /* starting point */
char *q=m->s;  /* end of usable area of vector */
```

and let's say that `m->d = sizeof(int);`

i want to find the middle of this vector;

i tried `*middle = p + (q - p)/2 * m->d;`

and it fails. it gives me a value that is not even in the vector;

I need some help getting that right.

Comment: I don't see how `v` and `s` are initialized????  Neither does `m` look initialized.  Please post code that at least compiles and runs and shows your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Let's ignore the possible portability issues)

The pointer to the physical middle of the array is

```
char *m = p + (q-p)/2;
```

since p and q are pointers to char. But beware: the expression calculates the middle of an array of char! 
To obtain a pointer that points to the middle in terms of blocks of size
 m->d, the expression is:

```
char *m = p + ((q-p)/(2*m->d))*m->d;
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
*middle = p + (q - p)/2 * m->d;
```

Takes the difference between two char pointers, divides by two, and then multiples by the size of the *actual* type.

Generally an int is at least 4x the size of a char, so that's going to index well out of range.

So I suspect you are invoking undefined behaviour.

You need the number of elements in the array/vector, not the number of bytes.